# Reactive Spring Security: using custom reactive method in @PreAuthorize Spring-EL

Tags: kotlin, reactive, spring-el, spring-boot-security

Is there any way to use reactive method in @PreAuthorize?

[environment]

- spring boot 3.0.1
- language: kotlin

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
```

```
    // My custom method
    fun role(authentication: Authentication): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    // My Controller
    @PreAuthorize("@org.role(authentication)")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    suspend fun health(exchange: ServerWebExchange) {
        exchange.response.statusCode = if(ready) HttpStatus.OK else HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY
    }
```

In above case, @org.role works find.
But I need to call suspend function in the 'role' method, so I changed like this.

```
    // My custom method
    fun role(authentication: Authentication): Mono<Boolean> {
        return mono {
            // call some suspend function
        }
    }
```

I faced following exception.
**

> Failed to evaluate expression '@org.role(authentication)'

**

I have to call suspend function in my custom method!!
The only way I found is like this, but I don't want to use 'runBlocking' due to performance.

```
    fun role(authentication: Authentication): Boolean {
        return runBlocking { true }
    }
```

PLEASE HELP ME!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Users have many kinds of permissions. Therefore, I have to bring only the required permissions dynamically in my custom method. That's why I have to call suspend function in the 'role' method.

Answer (score 0):

This issue due to ExpressionUtils.
After I upgrade spring boot to 3.0.4, this bug fixed.